# how to get the next cell in the same row when using poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using poi(`v4.0.0`) to import the excel document. But when I tried to get the next cell `carModelCell`, it always return null, this is my Java 8 code looks like:

```
public void verifyCar(Cell cell, int relativeRowIndex, Head head) {
        if (cell.getRowIndex() > 0 && head.getFieldName().equals("car")) {
            if (StringUtils.isBlank(cell.getStringCellValue())|| cell.getStringCellValue().equals("无车")) {
                return;
            }
            Cell carModelCell = cell.getRow().getCell(cell.getColumnIndex() + 1);
            if (carModelCell == null || StringUtils.isBlank(carModelCell.getStringCellValue())) {
                SparkUserParseResult result = new SparkUserParseResult();
                result.setSuccess(false);
                UploadSparkUserDataListener.parseSuccess.set(result);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am tried to get row from Cell, and get the next cell value with the same row and do some check, but the next cell `carModelCell` always return null. I have already sure the next cell of current row have a value. why would this happen? what should I do to fix this problem? This code block was in `CellStyleWriteHandler` which extend `AbstractCellStyleStrategy` in [easy excel](https://github.com/alibaba/easyexcel) (version 2.2.11):

```
public class CellStyleWriteHandler extends AbstractCellStyleStrategy {

    @Override
    protected void setContentCellStyle(Cell cell, Head head, Integer relativeRowIndex) {
        impl(cell, head, relativeRowIndex);
    }
}
```

I tried to get the last index num was 14, the current column index number was 13. the total column of my imported excel was 24, seems the easy excel did not pass the full column, is it possible to fix this problem? How to get the next cell of current row?

Comment: "I am sure the next cell have a value": And I am sure that it has not. `Row.getCell(int cellnum)` only returns `null` if the cell at index `cellnum` is not stored in that row. But that EasyExcel might not delivering a true `Cell` at all. Try whether `cell.getRow()` gets a `Row` and what  `cell.getRow().getLastCellNum()` gets as the index of the last cell contained in this row PLUS ONE.

Comment: `cell.getRow().getLastCellNum()` was 14, `cell.getColumnIndex()` was 13, the tatal column was 24.@AxelRichter

Comment: If `cell.getRow().getLastCellNum()` gets 14, then the last cell in that row has index 13. This is column `N`. And if `cell.getColumnIndex()` is 13, then `cell.getRow().getCell(cell.getColumnIndex() + 1)` must return null since you try to get the cell at index 14 (column `O`).

Comment: "seems the easy excel did not pass the full column": Please try understand how an Excel sheet is organized. It is not column wise, it is row wise. And only filled cells are stored in the row. So for example if row1 has columns A to C filled (A1, B1 and C1) but row2 only has columns A and C filled (A2 and C2), then cell B2 is not stored in row2. That's why `row2.getCell(1)` will return `null` .

Answer (score -1):

i also user poi to parse excel, i think problem in this line:

```
 Cell carModelCell = cell.getRow().getCell(cell.getColumnIndex() + 1);
```

code above is error, becase cell can get from row,like:

```
Cell cell = sheetColumnRow.getRow()
```

one raw can cantain many Cell，but you can not get complete row from Cell, Parse row Cell value can not reverse; wish help you;

Comment: What is `sheetColumnRow`? And how shall `.getRow()` return a `Cell`?

Comment: sheetColumnRow means excel sheet row, every sheet have many row;   Cell has a method call getRow(), you can not get a complete data row from a cell

Comment: "you can not get a complete data row from a cell": Of course you can. That's exactly what [Cell.getRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getRow--) does. It gets the `Row` from a `Cell` in that `Row`.